# Use Custom Authorization API in wso2am

Tags: java, wso2

I  have a following requirements.

I wants to use wso2 as getaway and generation of token and authentication. Of user.

I have a spring boot api which takes input a url and user id and based on these it decide whether user can access it or not

Now I wants to use this api in wso2am for authorizing the user for url..How can I used it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom handler and set it after the default authentication handler in the velocity xml.

See https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Writing+Custom+Handlers

Comment: Can I get requested url by user in handler like /user/get data/{userid}...?

Comment: Handler is written in Java. So you can do anything :)